# calling onchain view through other contract

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, on-chain-views

I am facing a weird issue on smartpy.
This is the onchain view added on fa2Fungible contract.

```
@sp.onchain_view()
    def check_operator(self, params):
        sp.set_type(params, sp.TRecord(owner=sp.TAddress, token_id=sp.TNat, operator = sp.TAddress))
        sp.verify(params.token_id <= self.data.last_token_id, "Token Id not found.")
        sp.result(self.data.operators.contains(
            sp.record(owner=params.owner, operator=params.operator, token_id=params.token_id)))
```

this is working fine while calling from the Views tab of bettercall.dev.
But whenever I called this from other contract, its giving issue .
The issue is it always returns false , even in case of true, it is returning false.
Here is the code where i called the above onchain view

```
@sp.entry_point
def test(self,  contract_address, token_id):
        sp.set_type(token_id, sp.TNat)
        is_operator = sp.view("check_operator", contract_address, sp.record(owner=sp.sender,
                                                                            token_id = token_id,
                                                                            operator = sp.self_address
                                                                            ), t=sp.TBool)
        local = sp.local("test", is_operator.open_some("Operator not found"))
        sp.if local.value == True:
            sp.failwith("if")
        sp.if local.value == False:
            sp.failwith("else")
```

this code always failswith the message else.
can you help me here ?

Comment: It seems like it is having issue from sp.self_address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mechanisms involved:

- `sp.transfer` adds a transfer operation to a list of operations executed at the end of the entrypoint.
- `sp.view` calls a view and returns the value directly.

When the view returns the result, the call to `update_operators` hasn't been done yet. If you create another entrypoint in your test contract and move the call to the view there, the result will corresponds to what you were expecting.

Here is an example of such test:

```
import smartpy as sp
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class MyNft(FA2.Fa2Nft):
    def __init__(self, metadata):
        FA2.Fa2Nft.__init__(self, metadata = metadata)

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def check_operator(self, operator):
        sp.result(self.data.operators.contains(operator))


class OperatorContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(is_operator=False)
    
    @sp.entry_point
    def add_operator(self, fa2, operator):
        contract = sp.contract(FA2.t_update_operators_params, fa2, "update_operators").open_some()
        sp.transfer(
            [
                sp.variant(
                    "add_operator",
                    sp.record(owner=sp.self_address, operator=operator, token_id=0)
                )
            ],
            sp.tez(0),
            contract
        )

    @sp.entry_point
    def check_operator(self, fa2, operator):
        self.data.is_operator = sp.view(
            "check_operator",
            fa2,
            sp.set_type_expr(sp.record(
                owner=sp.self_address,
                token_id = 0,
                operator = operator
            ), FA2.t_operator_permission), t=sp.TBool).open_some()
    

@sp.add_test(name="Simplest NFT")
def test():
    alice = sp.test_account("Alice")
    bob = sp.test_account("Bob")
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
    c1 = MyNft(
        metadata = sp.utils.metadata_of_url("https://example.com"),
    )
    sc += c1
    c1.update_operators([
        sp.variant(
            "add_operator",
            sp.record(owner=alice.address, operator=bob.address, token_id=0))]).run(sender=alice)
    sc.show(c1.check_operator(sp.record(owner=alice.address, operator=bob.address, token_id=0)))

    c2 = OperatorContract()
    sc += c2
    c2.add_operator(fa2=c1.address, operator=bob.address)
    c2.check_operator(fa2=c1.address, operator=bob.address)
    sc.show(c2.data)
```

Comment: In my case , update_operators access was called before this transaction. So basically, if I send address manually instead of sp.self_address, its working as expected. 
But whenever I call sp.self_address, it is acting randomly

Comment: Can you share a link to a minimal version of your code that has the problem?
I was able to create a test without problem.

Comment: https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1GPdAezSy4J4z4ZNYaqonVuRVL6ptTzscq/views
here is the fa2 contract view, if you check the  check_operator views,
with params 
owner = tz1g3pJZPifxhN49ukCZjdEQtyWgX2ERdfqP
token_id = 0
operator = KT1MWgJrvmcVyx2JvPFDAQYkn98Vm6Tj29NA(address of below contract)
It returns true. so it means the given contract address is given the operator access.

Comment: Now let’s move to the issue
here is the contract where I have called the views of the above fa2 contract
https://better-call.dev/ghostnet/KT1MWgJrvmcVyx2JvPFDAQYkn98Vm6Tj29NA/interact/


you can check the contract code here
https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmQWbxnnroRtSiMz5DFy5Crc6fKJUM1fPd1HJq7Ghpitkx&k=394b9f674b8a1f0ad325

Comment: here are two functions function1 and function2,
In function2 , I have provided the operator field using params, so it returns true in this case , working as expected.
In function1 , sp,self_address is sent as operator while calling views of fa2 contract , but in this case it is not working as expected. 

fa2 contract code where view is defined https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmNa3eTSngYEfSD9SYZEtX1SzE3wVhucbreNUpXNjk35pA&k=9bfc367bb80a3a570ce8

P.S. sp.faiilwith is added just to simulate and see whether the execution goes on the if block or else block

Comment: I originated the two contracts. In both cases (call to function1 and call to function2) I get a fail with sp.if.
Also the Michelson generated code is correct. I don't find any problem.
Advice: it's better to store a result in the storage instead of failing because I cannot see the transaction you've done in the explorer if they fail.